# How to load Proxy Auto Config (PAC) file in Android with java

Tags: java, android, proxy, pac

I want to create a proxy application only connectting specific web sites with proxy. I am thinking using pac file in this application, but i didn't find any source for this.

How can i load pac file programmatically in android? If there isnt any way to do this, how can i set proxy rule in android with java?

Comment: you found anything for this question.

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(